# Matching last occurrence before a previous match

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

How do I match the last occurrence of `foo` before the match of some number?

```
foo: A
  1
  2
foo: B
  1
foo: C
  2
```

A search for pattern `2` should return:

```
foo: A
foo: C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -v s='2' '/^foo:/{line=$0;next} $1==s{print line}' file
foo: A
foo: C
```

Comment: +1 but you should never use the letter `l` as a variable as it looks far too much like the number `1`, completely indistinguishable in some fonts.

Comment: I had to copy and paste that to Google just to be sure.

Comment: Advise well taken, changed `l` to `line` for readability purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This regex could definitely use some optimization, but it should work:

```
foo: [A-Z](?=(?:(?!foo)[^2])*2)
```

Demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/cX8gM0